# Set all elements in a ViewController to not be read by VoiceOver

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, accessibility

I am looking for a way to tell VoiceOver to not read an entire ViewController's worth of elements. The reason being, I have a button, which when pressed, presents a modal-ish VC onto the screen. I say modal-ish, because it is not a modal but instead a custom VC with a custom animation in, which does not actually cover the entire screen, so both the new VC and old VC are in the view at the same time and held in memory.

When a user swipes with two fingers to read all elements on screen, VoiceOver will read the elements in my new VC first, just like it should, it will then start reading the elements behind this VC that are now "hidden" (in quotes because they are not programmatically set to hidden, just hidden because the VC covers them up) and which shouldn't be read.

Is there any easy way to tell VoiceOver to skip that entire old VC? Or would I have to go through, element by element, and set the isAccessibilityElement to NO and then back to YES when the covering VC is dismissed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip voice over for a particular element, you have to disable the accessibility for that element (if it is set in the storyboard) else, you have to do it programmatically. You have to set `IsAccessibilityElement to NO`, to make voice skip that element.

There is also another way to do it. You have to make an array and give the elements which you want voice over to read, so when you want you give this array to: `accessibilityElements`, so that voice ovr wil only read the elemtns you given in the array. You can always modify the array as per your need.

Comment: So there's no easy way to add this functionality into the app? It loos like either a full refactoring to use an array for accessibility elements (a task that is far beyond the scope of the bug I'm trying to fix unfortunately, we have thousands of different view controller's we're working with) or to one-by-one set them to not be accessibility elements. I wish Apple would have made that a little easier than it is.

Comment: @BillL: you do over-complicate your implementation with no modal view because it would have been an easy solution. Otherwise, I don't see any other solution than those provided by Teja.